# Why unresolved inclusion?

Tags: c, embedded, fpga, intel-fpga, nios

I wonder why I get the error msg "unresolved inclusion" for `stddef.h`

[image]

The background is this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754434/altera-de2-hardware-timer-usage
where I try to solve the entire hw interrupt mechanism that I now divide into smaller problems to pinpoint what it is that makes the program not tick forward the time when I switch from polling to hardware timer.

What do you think is the matter? Does this problem have anything to do with that time is not ticking forward? When I did it with polling it worked:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30870/please-review-polling-for-nios-2

Now I want to do it with hw interrupts and I followed the manual but still have some issues that I hope you can help me with?

Comment: The unresolved inclusion has probably nothing to do with your hardware interrupts not working, these are two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `stdio.h` in your compiler's path. It could possibly be in some kind of `include` or `inc` folder. Then try to see if there is a `stddef.h` at the same place.

Try to remove the line including `stddef.h` and see if the compiler complains about `stdio.h`.

If you find both files, then you probably need to setup your build commands to add the path to the `std*.h` files (possibly with the `-I` flag).